# writing NSDate initialized with nil results in  EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, exc-bad-access

in one of my methods i am trying to clear `NSDate` data with `nil` and to save it to the defaults. when i am trying to save it my app received `"EXC_BAD_ACCESS"`
and crash.

any idea?
maybe there is another way to clear NSDate object?

Comment: Please add the code where you are doing this. "Clearing" then "Saving" doesn't make sense either.

Comment: i just noticed that it happened because i am trying to save a nil object to the default is it possible to clear nsdate without nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use

```
[userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"yourdatekey"]
```

Comment: i am still need this nsdate but empty in another place

Comment: you can't write nil to the NSUserDefaults - if you clear it using the function above next time you call objectForKey it will return nil - does that achieve the purpose - remember if you need the date in another class then just have the class property retain the original NSDate object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to write NIL into the userDefaults (which won't work), you may (A) write `[NSNull null]` into the userDefaults or (B) simply remove the value from the defaults entirely.

**Solution A:**

This however introduces the need of adding a bit more logic to your app.

**storage:**

```
[...]
id objectForDefaults = [NSNull null];
if (myDate != nil)
{
  objectForDefaults = myDate;
}
[userDefaults setObject:objectForDefaults forKey:@"mydate"];
[...]
```

**retrieval:**

```
[...]
NSDate *myDate = nil;
id objectFromDefaults = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"mydate"];
if (objectFromDefaults != [NSNull null])
{
  myDate = objectFromDefaults;
}
[...]
```

**Solution B:**

```
[userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"mydate"]
```

Comment: You can't write `NSNull` to `NSUserDefaults`